# Omit unnecessary parts in string array

Tags: c#, string, split

In C#, I have a string comes from a file in this format:

```
Type="Data"&gt;&lt;Path.Style&gt;&lt;Style
```

or maybe

```
Type="Program"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style
```

,etc. Now I want to only extract the `Data` or `Program` part of the Type element. For that, I used the following code:

```
string output;

var pair = inputKeyValue.Split('=');

if (pair[0] == "Type")
{
    output = pair[1].Trim('"');
}
```

But it gives me this result:

```
output=Data&gt;&lt;Path.Style&gt;&lt;Style
```

What I want is:

```
output=Data
```

How to do that?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you are not using tmpTypeString. I assume just a typo of some kind...

Comment: Split by `"`, then take only the first 2 sections.

Comment: Sorry for my typo, I edited that line.

Comment: @E_learner: the edit seemed to get rid of it entirely when it looked like a valid way to get the quote enclosed part of the text!

Comment: @gunr2171: how to take the first 2 sections?

Comment: @E_learner: Great! You have managed to split the long string at the "=". What about splitting at the "&gt;&lt;" first, before splitting the first of those at the "="?

Comment: @ArjanEinbu: sounds good. But in that case, I think there must always be "&gt;&lt" part in the input string array, right? The problem is, I am not sure about that.

Comment: @E_learner: You'll find out quickly if you try :)

Comment: @ArjanEinbu: I will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code example takes an input string, splits by double quotes, and takes only the first 2 items, then joins them together to create your final string.

```
string input = "Type=\"Data\"&gt;&lt;Path.Style&gt;&lt;Style";

var parts = input
    .Split('"')
    .Take(2);

string output = string.Join("", parts); //note: .net 4 or higher
```

This will make `output` have the value:

> Type=Data

If you only want `output` to be "Data", then do

```
var parts = input
    .Split('"')
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(1);
```

or

```
var output = input
    .Split('"')[1];
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answer!

Comment: I just came up with a new question: how about if I need to get the "Path.Style" part? For that I tried "var parts = input.Split(';').Skip(1).Take(1);" and some other similar ways, but what I got is an empty string. Could you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: @E_learner, that's a different format than what I have suggested. Try out using different splitting characters (you need to define what needs to be split). If you can't get it, post a new question.

Comment: ok, I will post a new question if I can't solve it then. Thank you.

Comment: I posted a new question here, could you take a glance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880386/select-specific-parts-in-string-array

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use a very simple regular express to parse out the bits that you want, in your case you want something that looks like this and then grab the two groups that interest you:

```
(Type)="(\w+)"
```

Which would return in groups 1 and 2 the values Type and the non-space characters contained between the double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing many split, why don't you just use `Regex` :

```
 output = Regex.Match(pair[1].Trim('"'), "\"(\w*)\"").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something, but what about this:

```
var str = "Type=\"Program\"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style";
var splitted = str.Split('"');
var type = splitted[1]; // IE Data or Progam
```

But you will need some error handling as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex?

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<=^Type=\").*?(?=\")");
var output = regex.Match(input).Value;
```

Explaination of regex

- `(?<=^Type=\")` This a prefix match.  Its not included in the result but will only match
                if the string starts with Type="
- `.*?` Non greedy match.  Match as many characters as you can until
- `(?=\")`        This is a suffix match. It's not included in the result but will only match if the               next character is "

Answer (score 1):

Given your specified format:

```
Type="Program"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style
```

It seems logical to me to include the quote mark (`"`) when splitting the `string`s... then you just have to detect the end quote mark and subtract the contents. You can use `LinQ` to do this:

```
string code = "Type=\"Program\"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style";
string[] parts = code.Split(new string[] { "=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] wantedParts = parts.Where(p => p.Contains("\"")).
    Select(p => p.Substring(0, p.IndexOf("\""))).ToArray();
```