# Select specific parts in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

In C#, I was given a string array from an XML file like this (this xml file is saved by an xaml based UI):

```
<Content>
&lt;Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System; ...   
TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center"&gt;my Data&lt;/TextBox&gt;&lt;/Grid&gt;
</Content>
```

Now I want to extract only the "my Data" part of this array. Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865632/omit-unnecessary-parts-in-string-array), I tried to do that in this way:

```
var pair = keyValue.Split('=');
if (pair[0] == "VerticalAlignment")
{
    var parts = pair[1].Split(';').Skip(1).Take(1);
    string  output= string.Join("", parts);
}
```

I also tried to split with different characters like '`&`', etc. But it gives me an empty output string. The expected result should be:

```
output = "my Data";
```

How to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that meant to be an HTML tag? Looks like something went wrong during posting here...

Comment: You should try to understand structure of this text and use regular expression. But it is not clear for me how this structure could like. Isn't it `"Center"<my Data>/TextBox<>/Grid<;`, seems strange to me.

Comment: As I understand you have part of HTML coming in string and you need value, regular expression is one solution, but you can load that String after decoding to XML object and then load mydata from it, it is valid XML/HTML code. If not using regular expression is best.

Comment: Yes, this array comes from an xml file.

Comment: I edited my question with more detail. Could you have any suggestion? I can parse this "Content" part of the xml, but the problem comes after that.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the code since it's formatting messed up a bit, but it looks like XML so using C# .NET's XML library is your best solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @UnTraDe - no, it is XML (or HTML) inside XML. Very common. Normally one would use XML api (like `XDocument`) to select inner XML/HTML content as string and than use XML or HTML parser (like HtmlAgilityPack) to read string and select necessary values.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Could you provide any sample code to do that here in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by parsing the xml string as `XElement`, and then get the value of its `TextBox` element.